# Avoiding using / overwriting global variables (with simple example)

Tags: python

```
TICKETPRICE = 10
ticketsRemaining = 100
userName = input("What is your first name?: ")


print("There are " + str(ticketsRemaining) + " tickets remaining.")


def ticketsWanted(userName):
    numOfTicketsWanted = input(
        "Hey {} how many tickets would you like? : ".format(userName))
    return int(numOfTicketsWanted)


requestedTickets = ticketsWanted(userName)


def calculateCost():
    ticketQuantity = requestedTickets
    totalCost = ticketQuantity * TICKETPRICE
    return totalCost


costOfTickets = calculateCost()


def confirm():
    global requestedTickets
    global costOfTickets
    tickets = requestedTickets
    totalCost = calculateCost()
    print("Okay so that will be " + str(tickets) +
          " tickets making your total " + str(totalCost))
    confirmationResponse = input("Is this okay? (Y/N) : ")
    while confirmationResponse == "n":
        requestedTickets = ticketsWanted(userName)
        costOfTickets = calculateCost()
        print("Okay so that will be " + str(requestedTickets) +
         " tickets making your total " + str(costOfTickets))
        confirmationResponse = input("Is this okay? (Y/N) : ")


confirm()


def finalStage():
    print("Your order is being processed.")

finalStage()
```

This is a simple program that:

Asks a user how many tickets they want
Calculates the cost of the tickets
Then asks if it's okay to go ahead with the purchase

How could I change the way I'm doing things to not have to overwrite the requestedTickets and costOfTickets global variables?
(they're being overwritten in the confirm function, if a user replies with an "n" declining the confirmation of purchase.)

I'm trying to learn best practices.

Comment: To avoid globals in a simple case like this, have functions return all the data that they produce, and take as parameters all the data that they require. That should be a simple refactor to make with this code.

Comment: The next step to go would be using classes aka. object oriented programming.

Answer (score 0):

```
TICKETPRICE = 10
ticketsRemaining = 100
userName = input("What is your first name?: ")

print("There are " + str(ticketsRemaining) + " tickets remaining.")


def ticketsWanted(userName):
    numOfTicketsWanted = input(
        "Hey {} how many tickets would you like? : ".format(userName))
    return int(numOfTicketsWanted)


def calculateCost(n_tickets):
    totalCost = n_tickets * TICKETPRICE
    return totalCost


def confirm(userName):
    n_tickets = ticketsWanted(userName)
    totalCost = calculateCost(n_tickets)
    print("Okay so that will be " + str(n_tickets) +
          " tickets making your total " + str(totalCost))
    confirmationResponse = input("Is this okay? (Y/n) : ")
    while confirmationResponse == "n":
        n_tickets = ticketsWanted(userName)
        costOfTickets = calculateCost(n_tickets)
        print("Okay so that will be " + str(n_tickets) +
              " tickets making your total " + str(costOfTickets))
        confirmationResponse = input("Is this okay? (Y/n) : ")


def finalStage():
    print("Your order is being processed.")


confirm(userName)
finalStage()
```